# Using RANDBETWEEN with NORMINV Num Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a random number between 1 and 5 (inclusive) with a mean 4 of.

I'm trying this code --

```
=NORMINV(RANDBETWEEN(1,5), 4, 1)
```

But it gives me a #NUM error. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

`NORMINV` is the *quantile* function for the normal distribution, and therefore takes a *probability* for its parameter (the other two define the mean and variance of the distribution). The probability must be in the range [0, 1). `RANDBETWEEN(1, 5)` will always give you an out-of-range value.

Drop the `RANDBETWEEN` function; replace with `RAND`.

Answer (score 0):

> ## NUM! -    Occurs if either:
>
> the supplied probability argument is < 0 or > 1

[Reference](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Norminv-Function.html)

Also, if you're on a version of Excel you should use `Norm.Inv`. `NORMINV` has been depreciated and is only still there for compatibility.

Try using

```
=NORM.INV(RAND(),4,2)
```

Comment: `>=1` due to, what I think is a numerical instability.